# Message is sent twice to the same channel after upgrading to spring integration 4

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I am trying to migrate from `spring-integration-core:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE` to `spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE`, `java 8`, `spring 4`. I am facing some issues after upgrading the spring integration version. I could see that the same message is being sent to the same channel twice(first time well formed xml and then xml that includes logger messages in that) without any proper reason. Everything was working fine before upgradation. What could be wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: No enough info to expose the issue. Perhaps something like DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration`  may help you to track that suspicious message. Maybe you have a mix of versions in your classpath. And so on. Without more useful information you are going to be along with that problem. Would be also great to see your minimal config with potential ability to play from our side etc. etc.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, Sorry for delayed response. I was on vacation for all these days. Thanks for the response. The issue is with some old code that is not in sync with the master and `STD` and `DEBUG` messages were logged in server.log of JBOSS. Replacing `CONSOLE` appender with `FILE` has solved the problem. However I am running into other issues after upgradation. I think `aggregator` is having some issues with upgradation. I will open a new thread after thorough investigation. Once again thanks much for your quick response.